# Union de 2 consultas sin alterar el orden de los resultados

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero ejecutar un query que me ordene una tabla primero por el campo prioridad y despues me los ordene alfabeticamente, por ejemplo:

---

```
SELECT * FROM tipos where prioridad between 1 and 5 order by prioridad
```

Este query me retorna 2 resultados ordenados en orden ascendente,

---

```
SELECT * FROM tipos WHERE prioridad is null ORDER BY nombre
```

Y este otro debería retornar los demás ordenándolos por nombre

---

Ahora quiero los resultados de ambos en la misma consulta y en ese orden pero al unirlos:

```
(SELECT * FROM tipos where prioridad between 1 and 5 order by prioridad ) union 
(SELECT * FROM tipos where prioridad is null order by nombre)
```

me retorna lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que a lo que quieres llegar es mucho más fácil que hacer un unión. `SELECT * FROM tipos ORDER BY prioridad, idtipos` Con esta consulta estamos diciendo que ordene por prioridad y luego por idtipos. Order by acepta varios campos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ORDER` siempre se aplica al final de cualquier consulta, en tu caso, lo estas aplicando en las subconsultas, pero no luego del `union` por lo que no puedes esperar ningún orden en particular. La solución sin tocar tu código sería algo así:

```
SELECT *
       FROM (
           SELECT * FROM tipos where prioridad between 1 and 5
           union 
           SELECT * FROM tipos where prioridad is null
       ) T
       ORDER BY case when prioridad is not null then 1 else 2 end,
                prioridad, nombre
```

El truco para separar los dos grupos es usar `case when prioridad is not null then 1 else 2 end`, creamos un argumento de orden de forma dinámica, poniendo adelante los casos dónde `prioridad` no es `NULL`, luego el orden, será la `prioridad` y el `nombre`. Con el segundo grupo, al ser la `prioridad` siempre `NULL` el orden determinante será el `nombre`.

Nota: Por otro lado, tu consulta puede simplificarse mucho, revisa la respuesta de Miguel al respecto.

Comment: Gracias, la consulta simplificada fue:```SELECT * from tipos
       ORDER BY case when prioridad is not null then 1 else 2 end,
                prioridad, nombre``` , en realidad me fue muy util el case, es lo que estaba buscando.

Answer (score 4):

Unifica tus consultas en una sola, con las dos condiciones, ya que son sobre la misma tabla. La consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tipos 
WHERE prioridad between 1 and 5 
    OR prioridad is null 
ORDER BY prioridad, nombre
```

De esta manera primero filtramos las prioridades con los valores que nos interesan y después por los valores nulos. A continuación ordenamos primero por prioridad y después por nombre.

A sugerencia de LPZadkiel, en la ordenación indicar que se puede ordenar ascendente (por defecto, `ASC`) o descendente (`DESC`). Incluso ordenar por cada campo de una manera diferente. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tipos 
WHERE prioridad between 1 and 5 
    OR prioridad is null 
ORDER BY prioridad DESC, nombre ASC
```

Si solo quieres indicar una condición de ordenamiento, siempre tiene que ir la última y ordenaría todos los campos de esa manera:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tipos 
WHERE prioridad between 1 and 5 
    OR prioridad is null 
ORDER BY prioridad, nombre DESC
```

Saludos!

Comment: yo agregaría lo de la palabra clave `ASC | DESC`